# Why VStack has different behavior between iOS13 and iOS14?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

In iOS13 `VStack` align its content center along the vertical direction, like this:

[image]

In iOS14 `VStack` align its content top along the vertical direction:

[image]

I use same code as below,

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
            Text("Row \(i)").foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

How to make the `VStack` align its top edge in iOS13?

Comment: It is not VStack, it is GeometryReader. I don't see why do you need it here - consider removing GeometryReader. ... or describe which layout do you want to achieve.

Comment: The code in my question is the smallest demo code, I do need GeometryReader to set vstack child view' height. Besides, same code produces different UI apparently, is this a bug?

Comment: See [GeometryReader Discrepancies with Previous OS Versions](https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-bug/)

Comment: @pawello2222 Having seen that and it solved my problem, thanks